# cannot import name supress Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

I have recently changed computer. After installing anaconda, I installed the package chaospy and attempted to run one of the programs that worked on my previous computer. However, a problem appears:

It says cannot import name supress. this should come from the library contextlib. https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

My working version is 2.7; this suppress shouldn't have any compatibility issues.

Anybody knows what is going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`contextlib.suppress` isn't in python 2.7. From the docs:

> contextlib.suppress(*exceptions)
> Return a context manager that suppresses any of the specified exceptions if they occur in the body of a with statement and then resumes execution with the first statement following the end of the with statement.
>
> As with any other mechanism that completely suppresses exceptions, this context manager should be used only to cover very specific errors where silently continuing with program execution is known to be the right thing to do.
>
> New in version 3.4.

The solution is to upgrade to using python >= 3.4 on your new computer.

Comment: You are right, I have checked and 10 days ago a new version of the software was developed for python 3. Thanks.